# Cocoa - Notification on NSUserDefaults value change?

Tags: cocoa, notifications, preferences

Let's say I have a key `@"MyPreference"`, with a corresponding value stored through `NSUserDefaults`.

Is there a way to be notified when the value is modified?

Or could it be done through bindings? (But this case, instead of binding the value to a UI element, I wish my object to be notified of the change, so that I can perform other tasks.)

I am aware that `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` can be observed, but this appears to be a all-or-nothing approach, and there does not appear to be a mechanism there to get at the specific key-value-pair that was modified. (Feel free to correct.)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Spent all day looking for the answer, only to find it 10 minutes after asking the question...

Came across a solution through Key-Value-Observing:

```
[[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] addObserver:self
    forKeyPath:@"values.MyPreference"
    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
    context:NULL];
```

Or, more simply (per comment below):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self
                                        forKeyPath:@"MyPreference"
                                           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                           context:NULL];
```

Comment: You could also call this method on `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and not have to prepend the "values." to the key path. The other parameters remain unchanged.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work as Quin suggested using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.  However, the string append is not needed as `...forKeyPath:@"values.MyPreference"...` will work.
Also, you will need to implement `- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;` to actually capture the event.

Comment: Hi TrevorL...even though stringByAppendingString: is not necessary, it helps when creating a generic method - (void) observePreference:(NSString *)pref { ...[@"values." stringByAppendingString:pref] ...

Comment: but this approach is only for Mac, not iOS

Comment: The `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` option isn't necessary. You can pass `0` as options.

Comment: In iOS seems to work only with the `standardUserDefaults` and not with custom `suiteName`'s defaults.

Comment: The first solution (that uses `NSUserDefaultsController`) works for Mac, but the second solution doesn't work.

Comment: Does KVO work when the user defaults is part of a shared suite and the values were changed by another process?

Answer (score 23):

Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "THE KEY", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
  // your logic
}

deinit {
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "THE KEY")
}
```

Comment: do not forget to remove observer since you're explaining complete approach

Answer (score 11):

And Apple employee advised to use NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification notification over here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/237718#237718

Comment: The disadvantage of this is, you cannot know WHICH of the settings was changed.

Comment: Yes, you'd think they would have put at least the changed key(s) in the userInfo dictionary of NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification, but no: "This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary."  Even worse, the only specification of when NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification is posted says that it is posted "when a persistent domain is changed".  It would probably take me 20 minutes of research to confirm exactly what that means, and then I'm not sure I'd trust it.

Comment: This method has another disadvantage: If an external program changes your app's defaults, e.g. using the cmd "defaults write" or with the Prefs Editor app, then you won't get notified. Using the KVO technique will notify you, OTOH.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DenNukem. I was using the `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew`. But this function started giving me the `BAD_ACCESS Code=1` error wherever I used the `NSUserDefault` in order to save other objects. In case you are using Key-Value Observer (KVC), just be aware of the Zombie issue on `NSUserDefaults`.

Here is the link to the solution:
[NSUserDefaults and KVO issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714161/nsuserdefaults-and-kvo-issues)