# How to get notified when a user default changed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, boolean, key-value-observing

I have a user default called `showSqliteSequenceTable` and this can be changed with a checkbox. I use this as follows, in a method called `-[SKDatabase reloadTables]`:

```
const char *tablesQuery = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"showSqliteSequenceTable"] ? "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'" : "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND NOT name='sqlite_sequence'";
```

What way can I get the `-[SKDatabase reloadTables]` message sent to every `SKDatabase` object in memory, or how can I make `SKDatabase` observe a user default? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSNotificationCenter to register for [NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification).

Comment: Also consider this [awesome solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1141404/991816).