# NSUserDefaults and KVO issues

Tags: ios

I'm using NSUserDefaults in my app and I would like to be notified when a particular value is changed. For that, I added the following lines in viewDidLoad:

```
NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[settings synchronize];
[settings addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"pref_server" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

And the method to be notified:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{

    NSLog(@"Change");

    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (object == settings && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"pref_server"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Server did change");
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the latter is never called...@"pref_server" is the item identifier I have set in Root.plist, in Settings.bundle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note, the documentation for `synchronise()` states: "Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."

Comment: If in trouble, please observe this very detailed blog article from one of the authors of NSUserdefaults: http://dscoder.com/defaults.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest making use of the appropriate notification: [NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-BAJIEFCA).

Search for AppPrefs in the Apple Documentation within Xcode and it'll show an example app which does exactly what you want to do. Just compile and run! It makes use of the [NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-BAJIEFCA).

This is the code being used to register an observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)
                                             name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: For Swift3: 
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
 selector: #selector(defaultsChanged),
 name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification,
 object: nil)`

Comment: The notification is not sent if the change is happening in another process, so KVO is the only way to check for changes on values on keys of the NSUserDefaults shared between the main Application and its Extensions (Today Widget, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

Interesting observation:

`[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` seems to be `KVO` compliant now as I am able to observe and bind to it's values. I'm running 10.7.2, using `Xcode 4.2, SDK 10.7, LLVM compiler 3.0` .

I can't seem to find this new behavior documented anywhere in the release notes.

Comment: I would assume it is an undocumented change in Lion. The release notes mention some changes under the hood made to defaults, so I guess KVO support changed at the same time. The need to use the controller for KVC/KVO is documented in the Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics for both Snow Leopard and Lion.

Comment: The question was specifically about [tag:ios].

Comment: Documentation states that it is compliant: "...You can use key-value observing to be notified of any updates to a particular default value...": developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Answer (score 3):

NSUserDefaults is not KVO compliant, but NSUserDefaultsController is. So you'd use:

```
NSUserDefaultsController *defaultsc = [NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController];
[defaultsc addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"values.pref_server" 
               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
               context:NULL];
```

Comment: NSUserDefaultsController ist not available in Cocoa Touch for iOS.

Comment: Documentation states that it is compliant: "...You can use key-value observing to be notified of any updates to a particular default value..." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Answer (score 3):

Though its not well documented, NSUserDefaults do support key-value observing in iOS7.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 11.3 this works and is documented:

> **Responding to Defaults Changes**
>
> You can use key-value observing to be notified of any updates to a particular default value.