# Loading data back from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsuserdefaults

*In ViewController3 the user can save some text via button click to the NSUserDefaults (to use it elsewhere). In the same ViewController there is also a tableView (used to delete specific items from NSUserDefaults)*

**So I have to load the data back with:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var exercisescopy = NSMutableArray(array: exercises)

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var exercisesListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("exercisesList") as? NSMutableArray

    if ((exercisesListFromUserDefaults) != nil){
        exercises = exercisesListFromUserDefaults!
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

**so that the data is there when you get to the third ViewController but how to get the data right back after saving a new element to NSUserDefaults? So that it is displayed in the tableView right now?**

Comment: The table view is in the same controller as is saving the data to user defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to observe changes in `NSUserDefaults`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714161/nsuserdefaults-and-kvo-issues) answer describes it well.

For swift it is:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, "reloadMyData:", NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification, nil)
```

Where `reloadMyData:` is your function to trigger table reloading.

Don't forget to strip the observer in `deinit` as in:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't wanna do this, **Using the NSUserDefault for passing Data**. `NSNotification` center is cool about that as @Burton suggested. If your data is really big you can use `CoreData`. If you really wanna do this that you intend here is how ...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
NSString *firstName = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstName"];
NSString *lastName = [defaults objectForKey:@"lastname"];
```

Here assummed that `firstname` & `lastname` were saved preiviously.