# KVO with shared NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: swift, ios7, ios8

I am having issues communicating between my host app and its extensions through communicating NSUserDefaults changes.

I initialized `NSUserDefaults` using  `init(suiteName:)`, added KVO observer using the `addObserver(...)` method and overrided the method  `observeValueForKeyPath(...)` but the method `observeValueForKeyPath(...)` is not called when I change the value corresponding to the observing `key`. It will be greatful if you help me to resolve this.

PS:here suite name is App groups name and `NSUserDefaults` created using `suiteName as group identifier` will be inside the private area for app groups.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714161/nsuserdefaults-and-kvo-issues

Comment: Hi @DanielGalasko. If its a `standardUserDefaults`  KVO works fine but in my case its different Its shared among apps and `userdefaults` entry created in a separate location ie. created a separate bundle for group and created `userdefault` file there and sharing among apps. Its same as inter - App communication.

Comment: Then you can't use KVO but need to use the notification that's posted across the suite:)

Comment: There is no `DistributedNotificationCenter` in iOS its only available in OSX.

Comment: see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284989/nsuserdefaultsdidchangenotification-and-today-extensions

Comment: We can register for `NSUserDifaultDidChageNotification` but that will notify only the current app if the current made any changes so It can't be applicable to app groups. If any app that is included in the `app group` made any changes , the other apps included in the `app groups` wont get notified.

Comment: Thats why you should look at MMWormhole and Darwin notifications. Alternatively you could just check if any of the keys have changed when your app becomes active:)

Comment: @DanielGalasko: Thanks dude. I believe that will works for me. :)

Comment: anytime! I posted a solution so people don't need to peruse these comments:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use KVO for UserDefaults in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963220/how-to-use-kvo-for-userdefaults-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html) you can use KVO on User Defaults.

This has already been answered around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424971/using-nskeyvalueobservation-to-observe-value-in-userdefaults) so I will not re-address it.

**Old Answer (iOS 9 and older)**

The short answer is that you can't use KVO or even NSNotificationCenter on `NSUserDefaults` to communicate changes between an App Extension and the containing App.

There's a [great post by Atomic Bird](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions) that looks at the ways of coordinating communication. In particular its interesting to look at his analysis of communicating user defaults changes:

> A possible alternative for app/extension notifications is to use the
> Darwin notification center via
> CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter, which actually is a little
> bit like NSDistributedNotificationCenter. There's some discussion of
> this by Wade Spires at Apple's dev forums site.
>
> I say "possible" because I'm not 100% confident of this continuing to
> work. In the documentation for this method, Apple notes that
>
> An application has only one Darwin notification center, so this
> function returns the same value each time it is called.
>
> So although this is apparently legal, it also sounds a lot like it
> violates the philosophy inherent in app extension restrictions, viz,
> that they can't access anything from the hosting app. This is why
> [UIApplication sharedApplication] is off limits in extensions. I can't
> help wonder if allowing CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter is
> an oversight that might get "fixed" at some point.

So I guess for now a good solution might be to use [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) as they implement the above solution.

Your other option is to use to check the user defaults every time your App becomes active and confirm whether any keys have changed, posting the relevant notifications etc.

Good luck

Comment: Is this still the case, in 2018 and with iOS 11?

Comment: It's no longer the case since iOS 10 https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html

Comment: There should be an option to flag an answer as "old" or "no longer valid"

Comment: Thanks @MartinRomañuk I did not actually realise this is stale so these comments are gold. Normally you just suggest an edit to the question but I have amended it. Have a great day

Answer (score 3):

Just tested, for iOS version later than 10.0, the KVO of the UserDefatuls works perfect fine across process.

Comment: Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html