# Continuously check and refresh userdefault integer

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to get my app to countinously check a `UserDefault` to see if it changed. If the default, when the `viewDidLoad`, is at 20 and a moment afterward decreases to 15 i want the `ViewController` to refresh and show the correct number. Here is my code for reading the default.

```
import UIKit

let Ironcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let Goldcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let Fiveth = UserDefaults.standard

let shipcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let empirecnt = UserDefaults.standard

var fiveth = Int()
var iron = Int()
var gold = Int()
var ships = Int()
var empires = Int()

class twenty: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var fiveth1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var iron1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gold1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ships1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var empire1: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var webViewBG: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "WebViewContent", ofType: "html")
    let htmlURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)
    let html = try? Data(contentsOf: htmlURL)

    self.webViewBG.load(html!, mimeType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: htmlURL.deletingLastPathComponent())

    if (Fiveth.value(forKey: "Fiveth") != nil){
        fiveth = Fiveth.value(forKey: "Fiveth") as! NSInteger!
        fiveth1.text = NSString(format: "Fiveth: %i", fiveth) as String
    }
    if (Ironcnt.value(forKey: "Ironcnt") != nil){
        iron = Ironcnt.value(forKey: "Ironcnt") as! NSInteger!
        iron1.text = NSString(format: "Iron: %i", iron) as String
    }
    if (Goldcnt.value(forKey: "Goldcnt") != nil){
        gold = Goldcnt.value(forKey: "Goldcnt") as! NSInteger!
        gold1.text = NSString(format: "Gold: %i", gold) as String
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able to see your UserDefault. And could you please explain what issue you are facing.

Comment: In your code doesn't have any part have `NSUserDefault`?

Comment: @DheerajD i updated my code, when the vied did load commands are called, the code is only done one time. I have a label that displays a userdefault and if the default is increased or decreased while in the viewcontroller i want the label to show the correct integer

Comment: Documentation for UserDefaults says that there is a UserDefaults.didChangeNotification for changes made in the same process or you can use "KVO"; here's a good pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714161/nsuserdefaults-and-kvo-issues

Comment: Thats not what i was looking for, i don't need to be notified. I have a label that shows an integer. The integer is saved using a userdefault. When the viewcontroller is called it will display the number that was last saved at that specific time,  and it won't check it again unless i change screens. Without make a refresh button i want to see how i would have the app show the correct value for the integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor all of these, you dont need to create so many reference :

```
let Ironcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let Goldcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let Fiveth = UserDefaults.standard

let shipcnt = UserDefaults.standard
let empirecnt = UserDefaults.standard

var fiveth = Int()
var iron = Int()
var gold = Int()
var ships = Int()
var empires = Int()
```

to sth like this:

```
var fiveth: Int {
    set {
        fiveth1.text = newValue
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "fiveth")
    }

    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "fiveth")
    }
}
```

then it will update both the userdefault and the label when you change the int