# iOS - Notification on NSUserDefaults Change When App Is In Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsusernotification

I have two applications that share an app group `@"group.edu.tds.poc.shared"`

Using NSUserDefaults of this app group, I am able to exchange data between the reader app and the writer app.

---

The Writer App writes data to the NSUserDefault

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults =
    [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.edu.tds.poc.shared"];

    [sharedDefaults setObject:stringToStore forKey:key];
    [sharedDefaults synchronize];
```

---

The Reader App reads the data from the NSUserDefault

```
 NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults =
    [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.edu.tds.poc.shared"];
    return [sharedDefaults stringForKey:@"key"];
```

I now want the reader app to be notified as soon as the writer app modifies the value for the key. I.e. Can I notify the reader app when the writer app is running in the foreground (Reader app is either running in the background or is not running).

I have implemented the marked solution but with no luck:

- [Cocoa - Notification on NSUserDefaults value change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141388/cocoa-notification-on-nsuserdefaults-value-change/1141404#1141404)
- [NSUserDefaults and KVO issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714161/nsuserdefaults-and-kvo-issues)

Call back only when the Reader App is in foreground state. (Wrote to the Shared Defaults using Reader app)

---

Any idea if this can be achieved?

Comment: If an app is in the background or is not running, then no code is running so it can't respond to any changes.