# Getting notification when UserDefaults are changed in Terminal

Tags: cocoa, notifications, terminal, nsuserdefaults

I want to get some notification in my Cocoa app when the user changes some of the user defaults from the Terminal by using "defaults write ....". Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you try whether this approach works for you: [Notification on NSUserDefaults value change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141388/cocoa-notification-on-nsuserdefaults-value-change?rq=1)?

Comment: I did try it but it doesn't work when the defaults are changed from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible. You should try using key-value observing (KVO) on `NSUserDefaultsController`. You would observe the `+sharedUserDefaultsController` for changes in the key path `values.<your default key>`.