# How to detect if OS X is in dark mode?

Tags: macos, cocoa, themes

My cocoa app has to change its behaviour when run in the new OS X "dark mode".

Is there a way to detect if OS X style is set to this mode?

Comment: stab in the dark - have you tried listening to `NSScreenColorSpaceDidChangeNotification` or examining `NSScreen` `colorSpace` property. On Mav's at the moment so can't check.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Don't think there's a cocoa way of detecting it yet, however you can use `defaults read` to check whether or not OSX is in dark mode.

```
defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle
```

Either returns `Dark` (dark mode) or returns domain pair does not exist.

**EDIT:**

As Ken Thomases said you can access .GlobalPreferences via NSUserDefaults, so

```
NSString *osxMode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AppleInterfaceStyle"];
```

If osxMode is `nil` then it isn't in dark mode, but if osxMode is `@"Dark"` then it is in dark mode.

Comment: The `defaults` command is just a wrapper around the `CFPreferences` API, as is `NSUserDefaults`. So, you can use either of those APIs rather than invoking `defaults`.

Comment: It's @"Dark", not @"dark" on my machine.

Comment: Is there any way of getting notified when the mode is changed?

Comment: @houbysoft Use [KVO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141388/cocoa-notification-on-nsuserdefaults-value-change)

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer thanks that looks like exactly what I want!

Comment: This works for detection, but in OS Sierra the only thing that changes when you programmatically set the mode to dark is the dock. Menu bar and notifications don't change. Any ideas on how to fix/change this? Thanks

Comment: @Husam, are you sure? It works in 10.14.3 beta 2 which I'm currently running.

Comment: Doesn't work on Catalina: "The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleInterfaceStyle) does not exist"

Comment: Catalina works perfectly. I just check NSString is DarkMode or no

Comment: @bas "Does not exist" probably means "light mode".

Comment: I can confirm (on Catalina), if in dark mode, then `defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle` returns "Dark", otherwise it returns "The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleInterfaceStyle) does not exist". Quite unintuitive :)

Comment: @Victor, does it work smoothly with the automatic switching between modes during night time from macOS?

Comment: @ggrelet it does! I use it in my Vim config to automatically switch between night and dark color schemes when macOS switches to night time. Works like a charm :)

Comment: It does not work for me: when on Automatic switch, the value of that pref is always `Dark`

Comment: Doesn't work on 11.3.1 on Apple Silicon: `The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleInterfaceStyle) does not exist`

Comment: `defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle` doesn't work on Big Sur 11.6 (Intel) either: `The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleInterfaceStyle) does not exist`

Comment: @pyb Did you read [the comment above from JeremyP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207077/how-to-detect-if-os-x-is-in-dark-mode#comment107021809_25214873)?

Comment: @FranklinYu yes, he's right. This is how I solved it in shell: `macos_is_dark() { test "$(defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle 2>/dev/null)" == "Dark" }`

Answer (score 40):

Swift 2 -> String ("Dark", "Light")

```
let appearance = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("AppleInterfaceStyle") ?? "Light"
```

Swift 3 -> Enum (Dark, Light)

```
enum InterfaceStyle : String {
   case Dark, Light

   init() {
      let type = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AppleInterfaceStyle") ?? "Light"
      self = InterfaceStyle(rawValue: type)!
    }
}

let currentStyle = InterfaceStyle()
```

Comment: Neat, I didn't know enums could have an `init()` method!

Answer (score 21):

You can detect this using `NSAppearanceCustomization` method `effectiveAppearance`, by checking for `darkAqua`.

Swift 4 example:

```
extension NSView {
    var isDarkMode: Bool {
        if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
            if effectiveAppearance.name == .darkAqua {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using `[NSAppearance.Name.darkAqua, NSAppearance.Name.vibrantDark].contains(effectiveAppearance.name)` to check both dark appearances

Answer (score 15):

You can also wrap it in a boolean if you don't feel like dealing with enums and switch statements:

```
/// True if the application is in dark mode, and false otherwise
var inDarkMode: Bool {
    let mode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AppleInterfaceStyle")
    return mode == "Dark"
}
```

Works on **Swift 4.2**

Answer (score 13):

For working with the new macOS Catalina you need to combine `AppleInterfaceStyle` with this new value introduced `AppleInterfaceStyleSwitchesAutomatically`.

Here is some pseudo-code explaining how to:

```
theme = light //default is light
if macOS_10.15
    if UserDefaults(AppleInterfaceStyleSwitchesAutomatically) == TRUE
        if UserDefaults(AppleInterfaceStyle) == NIL
            theme = dark // is nil, means it's dark and will switch in future to light
        else
            theme = light //means it's light and will switch in future to dark
        endif
    else
        if UserDefaults(AppleInterfaceStyle) == NIL
            theme = light
        else
            theme = dark
        endif
    endif
else if macOS_10.14
    if UserDefaults(AppleInterfaceStyle) == NIL
        theme = light
    else
        theme = dark
    endif
endif
```

You can check a macOS sample app here: https://github.com/ruiaureliano/macOS-Appearance.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of this sample app.)

Answer (score 12):

I would check against all dark appearances like so

```swift
extension NSView {

    var hasDarkAppearance: Bool {
        if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
            switch effectiveAppearance.name {
            case .darkAqua, .vibrantDark, .accessibilityHighContrastDarkAqua, .accessibilityHighContrastVibrantDark:
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        } else {
            switch effectiveAppearance.name {
            case .vibrantDark:
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```swift
if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
    inputTextView.textColor = (NSApp.effectiveAppearance.name == NSAppearance.Name.darkAqua ? NSColor.white : NSColor.black)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**2020 | SWIFT 5.1:**

## WAY 1:

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var scheme
```

## WAY 2:

doesn't update swiftUI in case of theme change. Need to realize additional logic for view upd:

```
#available(OSX 10.14, *)
static private var isLight: Bool { NSApp.effectiveAppearance.name == NSAppearance.Name.aqua }

#available(OSX 10.14, *)
static private var isDark: Bool { NSApp.effectiveAppearance.name == NSAppearance.Name.darkAqua }
```

Comment: Just add an observer for the `AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification` distributed notification and go from there.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a complete answer to the  question because the questioner doesn't say what their use case is. If they want completely different behaviour of their app, the below  behaviour doesn't work. However, if they only want to change the colour of some custom view, this is [the Apple blessed way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface).

The thing to do is to stop using absolute colours  and start using semantic colours. This means defining a "colour set" for each colour you want to use in the assets catalog. Having defined your colour set, in the inspector, set the device to "Mac" and the appearance to "Any, Light, Dark". You will then get three colour wells, "any" is for legacy operating systems that do not support dark mode, "light" and "dark" should be obvious.

Here is an example:

[image: Defining a colour set that supports dark mode]

This defines a colour that will be white in dark mode and black in light mode or on legacy operating systems.

Once you have defined a colour set, you can retrieve the colour in your `draw(_ dirtyRect:)` as follows:

```
let strokeColour = NSColor(named: NSColor.Name("gridColour")) ?? NSColor.black
```

In the above, I default to black if the colour set does not exist to deal with the optional type of `NSColor(named:)`.

Answer (score 2):

The only safe way to check for dark mode is to use the following:

```swift
let viewUsesDarkMode: Bool
if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
    viewUsesDarkMode = view.effectiveAppearance.bestMatch(from: [.aqua, .darkAqua]) == .darkAqua
} else {
    viewUsesDarkMode = false
}
```

This is the only solution that works in all cases. Whether you have views with mixed appearances, or if you allow your app to use a different appearance than the system default, or if you configure your system to use the high contrast appearances.

Comment: This could be modified to check for both regular and vibrant. ```if #available(macOS 10.14, *) {
            if view.effectiveAppearance.bestMatch(from: [.aqua, .darkAqua]) == .darkAqua || view.effectiveAppearance.bestMatch(from: [.vibrantLight, .vibrantDark]) == .vibrantDark {
                viewUsesDarkMode = true
            } else {
                viewUsesDarkMode = false
            }
        } else {
            viewUsesDarkMode = false
        }```

Comment: @SouthernYankee65 This is unnecessary. `bestMatch` chooses the closest appearance from the provided options. In this case, if `effectiveAppearance` happened to be `.vibrantDark`, then the result would still be `.darkAqua`.

Answer (score 2):

This can extract the current mode from the GlobalPreferences file.

```
sw_vers
```

ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.5.1
BuildVersion:       22G90

```
if [[ $(defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist  AppleInterfaceStyle 2>/dev/null) = Dark ]]; then
    echo 'Dark'
else
    echo 'Light'
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at NSAppearance.Name (in Swift speak) - 
there are variants:

.darkAqua

.accessibilityHighContrastDarkAqua

.accessibilityHighContrastVibrantDark