# How do I detect dark mode using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, macos-darkmode

Windows and macOS now have dark mode.

For CSS I can use:

```css
@media (prefers-dark-interface) { 
  color: white; background: black 
}
```

But I am using [the Stripe Elements API, which puts colors in JavaScript](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#the-elements-object)

For example:

```js
const stripeElementStyles = {
  base: {
    color: COLORS.darkGrey,
    fontFamily: `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"`,
    fontSize: '18px',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: COLORS.midgrey
    },
    ':-webkit-autofill': {
      color: COLORS.icyWhite
    }
  }
}
```

**How can I detect the OS's preferred color scheme in JavaScript?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if Dark Mode is enabled in macOS Mojave on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730640/how-can-i-detect-if-dark-mode-is-enabled-in-macos-mojave-on-my-website)

Comment: [This second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730640/how-can-i-detect-if-dark-mode-is-enabled-in-macos-mojave-on-my-website) isn't marked as accepted, but covers how to use JavaScript with `window.matchMedia`

Comment: I couldn't get the `@media (prefers-dark-interface)` media query to work in Chrome 80 (like you mentioned), but `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` did.

Comment: Just posted a one-liner solution. Please, check it out, if you can! Thanks!

Answer (score 689, accepted):

```js
if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    // dark mode
}
```

To watch for changes:

```js
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', event => {
    const newColorScheme = event.matches ? "dark" : "light";
});
```

Comment: I'll just leaver this here: `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', function(e) { console.log('changed!!');})`

Comment: Note that `prefers-color-scheme: dark` does not seem to work in Edge. Not in CSS or Javasript.

Comment: @VDWWD old Edge or new Edge (Chromium-based)?

Comment: The version I have is `Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0` with `Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363`. But I found out this is an old version. Apparently Windows Update does not automatically updates Edge... Updated manually and now it works.

Comment: Yes, that's the "old" version. As far as I know, the only way to detect dark mode in the EdgeHTML-based Edge is through the Windows APIs which are only available if the user "installs" the app through the Windows Store. I wouldn't bother with this as the Windows feature update 2004 (rolling out right now) replaces the "old" Egde with the new Chromium-based Edge.

Comment: This code doesn't work on Xiaomi's mobile default browser (Mi browser), but works in Chrome browser, Please help

Comment: @JafaruddeenAnsari it seems Xioami browser does not support this standard browser API. There is nothing you can do most likely. Maybe Xiaomi has a non-standard proprietary API, but I doubt that.

Comment: Just teste with  Chrome 86.0.4240.75 and Win 10 1909 and runs perfect$

Comment: @MarkSzabo can i use this scenario for all browsers like safari or firefox? or i've to check another property instead `(prefers-color-scheme: dark)` for them?

Comment: I am using this in Cordova iOS App (WKWebView). works perfectly!

Comment: I am using Edge 100.0.1185.44 (Official Build) (64-bit) on windows 10 and the above does not work. The above code works fine on Chrome and Firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: The TypeScript event type for this event handler is `event: MediaQueryListEvent`.

Comment: Does not work on chrome version 121.0.6167.85.

Answer (score 41):

You can check the CSS [Media-Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp) directly with JavaScript

> The window.matchMedia() method returns a MediaQueryList object
> representing the results of the specified CSS media query string. The
> value of the matchMedia() method can be any of the media features of
> the CSS @media rule, like min-height, min-width, orientation, etc.

To check if the Media-Query is true, the `matches` property can be used

```js
// Check to see if Media-Queries are supported
if (window.matchMedia) {
  // Check if the dark-mode Media-Query matches
  if(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches){
    // Dark
  } else {
    // Light
  }
} else {
  // Default (when Media-Queries are not supported)
}
```

To update the `color-scheme` dynamically based on the user's preference, the following can be used:

```js
function setColorScheme(scheme) {
  switch(scheme){
    case 'dark':
      console.log('dark');
      
      break;
    case 'light':
      console.log('light');
      // Light
      break;
    default:
      // Default
      console.log('default');
      break;
  }
}

function getPreferredColorScheme() {
  if (window.matchMedia) {
    if(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches){
      return 'dark';
    } else {
      return 'light';
    }
  }
  return 'light';
}

function updateColorScheme(){
    setColorScheme(getPreferredColorScheme());
}

if(window.matchMedia){
  var colorSchemeQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  colorSchemeQuery.addEventListener('change', updateColorScheme);
}

updateColorScheme();
```

Answer (score 17):

According to [MediaQueryList - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList#Methods), `addListener` is the correct way to listen to the change. `addEventListener` is not working for me on iOS 13.4.

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addListener(function (e) {
  console.log(`changed to ${e.matches ? "dark" : "light"} mode`)
});
```

Comment: Also from MDN - This is basically an alias for EventTarget.addEventListener(), for backwards compatibility purposes.

Comment: Just to quote the mentioned MDN, as I was confused and looked it up: " `addListener()`
Adds to the MediaQueryList a callback which is invoked whenever the media query status—whether or not the document matches the media queries in the list—changes. This method exists primarily for backward compatibility; **if possible**, you should instead use `addEventListener()` to watch for the change event."

Comment: According to MDN it's deprecated

Answer (score 12):

Here's a one-liner based on [SanBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60971231/2419808):

```
const getPreferredScheme = () => window?.matchMedia?.('(prefers-color-scheme:dark)')?.matches ? 'dark' : 'light';
```

Comment: love the optional chaining. never seen that ?. operator before. very cool.

Answer (score 6):

Check the [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) option:

```js
function getTheme() {
  if(window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme:dark)").matches) {
    return "dark";
  } else {
    return "light";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution - unfortunately this doesn't look like valid JavaScript. If you want to fix it and edit your answer though I'll upvote it!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
const theme = window.matchMedia?.("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? "dark" : "light"
```

Comment: Nice use of optional chaining. Since this only has two results you could make it a boolean called `isDark` for tighter code.

Answer (score 4):

## Before typing your JavaScript:

You can use CSS to make a `@media` query that says to have an `::after` pseudo class on the `body` element that has a different text depending on the color-scheme of the user. In order to make sure the `::after` on the `body` element doesn't confuse users, add a `display: none;` on the after element.

### CSS Code:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){
    body::after{
        content: 'd';
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme:light){
    body::after{
        content: 'l';
        display: none;
    }
}
```

## Now for your JavaScript:

Since we have an object in the document to select, we can get the `::after` pseudo class of the `body` element. We need to get the content of it, just make sure your CSS loads before your JavaScript does! `'d'` for **d**ark mode, and `'l'` for **l**ight mode.

### JavaScript Code:

```
var colorScheme = getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').content;
// d for dark mode, l for light mode.
```

## Why this could be useful

You can do this in CSS and HTML, but why would you do it in JavaScript?

You would use JavaScript because you might have to add an `img` element, but the image has text, so you got 2 images, one for light mode, the other for dark mode. So, you could use JavaScript to change the `src` attribute's value of the `img` element to the correct URL based off of the color-scheme.

There is probably more uses, but that is the use I can think of.

## Sources:

I learned `getComputedStyle` function from [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20way%20in,The%20second%20parameter%20is%20optional.&text=This%20will%20do%20alert%20the%20value%20of%20pseudo%20element.).

I learned `@media (prefers-color-scheme:`*color scheme to detect*`)` from [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme).

I learned how to get `.content` of computed style from seeing it as a code suggestion on VSCode as I typed `getComputedStyle(document.body,':after')` and it working as I expected it to. (If I saw it on an article, I can't find which I visited)

Comment: Loading different images for dark and light mode, it probably better to use the <picture> tag. One can define fail safe loading, orientation, width, height and color scheme, without using JS at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap 5 and you want to default to dark if JavaScript is off use this:

```js
// don't hurt peoples eyes /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const matchPrefersLight = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme:light)');
if (matchPrefersLight.matches) {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', 'light');
}
matchPrefersLight.addEventListener('change', event => {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', event.matches ? "light" : "dark");
});
```

And also use your top element:

```html
<html lang="en-US" data-bs-theme="dark">
```

or whatever other language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [1k script](https://github.com/orca-scan/appearance-changed-event) that adds `appearance-changed` event to detect OS theme changes.

```js
// fires every time the OS theme changes
window.addEventListener('appearance-changed', function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail); // `light`, `dark`
});
```

Also adds `window.appearance` which you can use to get the current OS theme:

```js
switch (window.appearance) {
    
    case 'light': {
       // do some light theme stuff
    } break;

    case 'dark': {
       // do some dark theme stuff
    } break;
}
```

It's open source on [GitHub](https://github.com/orca-scan/appearance-changed-event).

Answer (score 0):

for people using react, see the [useDarkMode](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-dark-mode) hook. Which listens for changes and also allows you to toggle/change the dark mode.

```
import { useDarkMode } from 'usehooks-ts'

export default function Component() {
  const { isDarkMode, toggle, enable, disable } = useDarkMode()
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current theme: {isDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light'}</p>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
      <button onClick={enable}>Enable</button>
      <button onClick={disable}>Disable</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You need [color-mode](https://color-mode.nuxtjs.org/) If you develop your app using nuxt.