# Disabling dark mode in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm maintaining an Angular application and have encountered some bugs related to the dark mode feature. Surprisingly, I couldn't find any explicit code that enables or implements this feature within our application. It seems that the dark mode is being activated automatically by the browser. Since our primary focus isn't on refining this feature and we didn't intend to invest much time into it, I've been tasked with removing the dark mode altogether.

I've tried searching for solutions, but all I could find were guides on how to implement a dark mode feature. While one potential solution could be to make the dark mode colors identical to the light mode, it seems inefficient to duplicate code for this purpose.

Comment: An angular app doesn't have any dark mode included by default. If it is there, then the developer (you?) put it there. Or maybe a plugin in the browser triggers this? Not much we can help here without more context.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. In that case I at least know that its not some default Angular value and I can look for a Plugin that might trigger it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to prevent force dark mode by system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989878/how-to-prevent-force-dark-mode-by-system)

Comment: Yes i just discovered this page and i think this is the problem. Thanks for the help