# Chrome browser always return false for window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-theme

I'm triying to get the theme of the browser using
**window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;**
This works for all browsers except Chrome. In Chrome it will always returns false even if I was in dark mode.
Can anyone please help to resolve this issue in chrome.

Comment: [It returns `true` for me](https://jsfiddle.net/5jqe6ypo/) on Chrome while in Dark mode. How do you set it to dark mode?

Comment: I'm enabling chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark also tried through appearance settings

Comment: @Ivar can you please tell me how you are setting

Comment: I have enabled it via the OS (Windows).

Comment: That works for me also, but I want it while changing through browser settings

Comment: See [How to detect #enable-force-dark flag on Chrome v78+ using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58735674/how-to-detect-enable-force-dark-flag-on-chrome-v78-using-javascript)