# iOS Light- or dark mode in JS

Tags: javascript, ios, sirishortcuts, ios-darkmode

Can someone help me with making a JS code that return with document.write “Light” when users have light mode on and “Dark” when they have dark mode on (on their iOS device)

Comment: In CSS there is a dark mode media query https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393880/how-do-i-detect-dark-mode-using-javascript):

```
if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    // dark mode
}
```

Comment: For future reference, if a question is a duplicate you should use the "Flag" function on the question to indicate this, rather than adding an answer.