# How do you get a user's system color scheme preference?

Tags: javascript

For example, the new Stack Overflow feature, Dark Mode has an option to use the system default between light mode and dark mode. How do they tell what the system default is with JavaScript? And if not with JavaScript, how do you find it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: Does that work on mobile too?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=prefers-color-scheme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect dark mode using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393880/how-do-i-detect-dark-mode-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.matchMedia` to detect the user's preferred color scheme with JavaScript.

```js
const result = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
console.log(result.matches); // TRUE if user prefers dark mode
```