# Changing color of Discord widget based on preferred system color scheme

Tags: javascript, html, widget, discord

I’m trying to do something like this:

```
if preferred color scheme : dark {
   <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=123&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
} else {
   <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=123&theme=light" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do so in JavaScript. Any thoughts?

Comment: You somehow need access to the preferred color scheme data, and then check if it's dark. Make sure you compare data of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795495/6911703) shows a way to detect a user's dark mode in JavaScript:

```js
if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    //dark mode
}
```

So you would want something like this:

```js
if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    // dark mode
    // append to element/body:  <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=123&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
} else {
    // light mode
    // append to element/body:  <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=123&theme=light" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

```
<iframe src="https://discord.com/widget?id=855719048319074325&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.