# How to detect if OS X is in dark mode in browser JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Similar to "[How to detect if OS X is in dark mode in browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840168/how-to-detect-if-os-x-is-in-dark-mode-in-browsers)" only for JavaScript.

How to detect if the user's system is in the new macOS Dark Mode in Safari/Chrome/Firefox and get the result as a boolean value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) function to check the compliance with the `prefers-color-scheme` media rule:

```js
const isDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
// or
const isLight = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches;
```

You can also get a notification when the Dark Mode turns on/off:

```js
const media = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

media.addListener(() => {
  alert(`The mode has changed to ${media.matches ? 'dark' : 'light'}`);
});
```