# How to detect if the OS is in night light mode in browsers?

Tags: css

Night light is a mode where the colors of your display are shifted to the warmer end of the color spectrum after dark. It is supported both under [Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/4027563/windows-10-set-your-display-for-night-time) and [MacOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207513) (called night shift by Apple).

Is there a way to detect if night light is enabled via the browser?

We would like to change our site's design to be night-mode friendly based on the current operating mode.

(This question should not be confused with the user preference for [light-on-dark color scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-on-dark_color_scheme) a.k.a. "dark mode" which [can be queried via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840168/how-to-detect-if-the-os-is-in-dark-mode-in-browsers))

Comment: I was rather under the impression that you didn't need to do anything; e.g. your #ffffff would be displayed as "night light white" anyway.

Comment: We do have a color scheme that has some issues with exactly this. Some contrasts, highlights become less pronounced/look weird.