# Detect dark mode in macos from python

Tags: python, macos, macos-mojave

I am writing a PyQt app and I have to add a patch so that the font is readable on macos with dark mode enabled:

```
app = QApplication([])
# Fix for the font colours on macos when running dark mode
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    p = app.palette()
    p.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(101, 101, 101))
    p.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, QColor(231, 231, 231))
    app.setPalette(p)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```

The issue with this patch is then it makes things unreadable on macos with light mode.

Is there a way I can detect dark mode on macos from python or using a standard shell command through subprocess?

EDIT:
As of PyQt 5.12 the dark mode fix is no longer required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207077/how-to-detect-if-os-x-is-in-dark-mode), you could install `pyobjc` and use `NSUserDefaults`:

```
>>> from Foundation import NSUserDefaults
>>> NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey_('AppleInterfaceStyle')
'Dark'
```

Answer (score 10):

In case you do not want to import pyobjc, you can use [Darkdetect](https://github.com/albertosottile/darkdetect), a dedicated package that uses only dependencies provided with standard Python distributions.

Usage:

```
import darkdetect

>>> darkdetect.theme()
'Dark'

>>> darkdetect.isDark()
True

>>> darkdetect.isLight()
False
```

Darkdetect is also available on PyPI: `pip install darkdetect`.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of Darkdetect.

Comment: Nice find, @asottile!