# Using MacOS system appearance for PyQt5 app compiled by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have an app written on python + PyQt5. When I'm launching it from source it uses MacOS system appearance -- light colors for light appearance and dark for dark. But when I build the app using Pyinstaller it ignores system styles completely, and always use light color mode.
How can I automatically apply system styles to my widgets, or at least detect system appearance and do it manually?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701288/detect-dark-mode-in-macos-from-python

Comment: I'm not sure about mac but copying all plugins dir from `<python_libs_dir>/site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins` to `<pyinstaller_dir>/bincache01_py37_64bit\pyqt5\qt\plugins` fixed the similar problem for me. Also disable `upx` when building the app.

Comment: eyllanesc, thank you for your answer! Now I can, at least, detect dark mode and deal with CSS and pallets.
M.R., I don't have directory "Qt" in PyQt5, and directory "bincache..." at Pyinstaller dir. Maybe, it is platform-specific?