# SwiftUI MenuBarExtra icon and dark mode

Tags: swiftui, menubarextra

I want my icon to be light/dark according to current system color theme,
but I never seem to get the dark color image to show, its always the light image that shows up

```
MenuBarExtra("", image: "my image name") {
    Text("some text")
}
```

also tried using label but the "MenuLogoView" does not get any callback while switching color mode:

```
MenuBarExtra {
    MenuView(model: menuModel)
} label: {
    MenuLogoView()
}
```

```
struct MenuLogoView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
...
```

but "colorScheme" never seems to change

if I use the same image resource in other places of my code it works well for both light/dark color theme modes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that, indeed, `MenuBarExtra`s don't get their `colorScheme` environment set to the correct value. I'm not sure if this is intentional.

One rather nasty trick is to get the "real" color scheme from one of your `View`s in a window.

```
@State var realColorScheme: ColorScheme = .light
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView(colorBinding: $realColorScheme)
    }
    MenuBarExtra {
        MenuView(model: menuModel)
    } label: {
        Image("my_image")
            .environment(\.colorScheme, realColorScheme)
    }
}
```

where `ContentView` is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var color
    
    @Binding var colorBinding: ColorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        // content here...
            .onAppear {
                colorBinding = color
            }
            .onChange(of: color) {
                colorBinding = $0
            }
    }
}
```

An alternative way is to detect dark mode by reading `UserDefaults` with `@AppStorage`, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25214873/5133585). This would work even if your app is only a `MenuBarExtra`. The user defaults updates a bit more slowly than the `@Environment` approach above though, from my experience.

```
@State var realColorScheme: ColorScheme = .light
@AppStorage("AppleInterfaceStyle") var colorName: String?

var body: some Scene {
    MenuBarExtra {
        MenuView(model: menuModel)
    } label: {
        Image("my_image")
            .onAppear {
                realColorScheme = colorSchemeFromUserDefaultsValue(colorName)
            }
            .onChange(of: colorName) {
                realColorScheme = colorSchemeFromUserDefaultsValue($0)
            }
            .environment(\.colorScheme, realColorScheme)
    }
}

func colorSchemeFromUserDefaultsValue(_ value: String?) -> ColorScheme {
    if value == "Dark" {
        return .dark
    } else {
        return .light
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the first workaround seems to work, I believe this is a bug on Apple side

Comment: This is likely intentional. The appearance of menu bar extras doesn't (and arguably shouldn't) depend on which mode the user has selected. It depends on the brightness of the wallpaper under the menu. Images that have `asTemplate` set to true automatically switch bright and dark. But now the bonus question: how would you determine programmatically whether you should render something dark or bright?

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg Oh you're right! I didn't think that deeply about the question's context when I was answering. I didn't notice that the appearance changes with the wallpaper! From a quick search around, no one seems to have figured out the "bonus question". Menu icons are not intended to be non-template images, probably. That said, I'm not convinced that there is *never* a case where the menu icon should depend on the color scheme.

Comment: Yes, I was fishing with that bonus question. Couldn't find an answer either. I did find out how to render SwiftUI views into a template image, though, in case that's useful: https://github.com/erikdoe/ccmenu2/commit/fc978a8b03e6f3eb8082f817d8e137dbe0921dd0#diff-8b604ba17be43cf7039c954dc3569e28c7b0a021de8870f10d9fa7abfe9ef20c