# FSEvents : plist file written using defaults detecting unexpected event path

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fsevents

I have a plist file which is being monitored for changes using FSEvents API.

```
_fileStream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                  &fsevents_apps_callback,
                                  &context,
                                  (__bridge CFArrayRef)[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"/"],
                                  kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow,
                                  (CFAbsoluteTime)0.2,
                                  kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents);

// start the stream on the main event loop
FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(_fileStream,
                                 CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                                 kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
FSEventStreamStart(_fileStream);
```

I am using sudo defaults to write to plist.
 Sudo defaults /Library/Application Support/myApp/file.plist

In my callBack function , the event path is turning out to be /Library/Application Support/myApp/file.plist.52738

I am concerned with it being detecting as file.plist.2332(some random number) and not file.plist

Any Inputs why this behaviour is seen ?

If we use PlistBuddy to write it , it all looks fine and event path is /Library/Application Support/myApp/file.plist.

Comment: Why do you use sudo defaults to write? Can't you use NSUserDefaults and watch for changes like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141388/cocoa-notification-on-nsuserdefaults-value-change

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could be seen because of this:

- In OS X 10.9 and newer there is a special deamon doing all the defaults reading and writing. it's called  `cfprefsd` and runs as root as well as the logged in users. It does all of the caching and flushing and coordination with persistency on disk.