# NSUserDefaults for NSMatrix

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults

Thanks for the help. I have an NSMatrix with 2 radioButtons set to retain the user defined selection using the *selectedIndex* binding. I also have 2 button actions that toggle the same NSMatrix radioButton selection(s).

```
[sizeMatrix selectCell:[sizeMatrix cellWithTag:0]];
```

and ...

```
[sizeMatrix selectCell:[sizeMatrix cellWithTag:1]];
```

In these respective (button) actions, I need to set the necessary NSUserDefaults for the linked NSMatrix selection. I tried the following with no success:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"myKey"];
```

How do I set this up? As well, how do I set the userDefault in awakeFromNib;?

Thanks again.

-paul.

Comment: As you are talking about *binding* why don't you simply ***bind*** `selectedIndex` to `Shared User Defaults Controller` with appropriate key in Interface Builder?

Comment: Thanks, The NSMatrix object is implemented as you describe and works as expected. I have two separate NSButton actions that toggle the selection of the noted NSMatrix radioButtons. As it stands the code in these actions doesn't set and/or retain the userDefault setting. I need to do this programmatically.

Comment: When you bind the `selectedIndex` of the matrix due to KVO the value is saved to UserDefaults automatically when it changed. That's the main benefit of Cocoa Bindings.

Comment: Well it's not working as you describe. The matrix setting is retained when I directly toggle it's radioButtons. That's not the issue. As noted I have two entirely independent push button actions (as described above) that programaticlly flip the state of the (2) matrix radioButtons. When I use either of the button actions, the matrix radio buttons state work as expected. However the radio button state is not loaded in the userDefaults. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Did you check the user defaults? Is the same `myKey` written by the matrix and in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try observer patttern instead of action pattern.

[Cocoa - Notification on NSUserDefaults value change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141388/cocoa-notification-on-nsuserdefaults-value-change)

Comment: Isn't this what a binding does?

Comment: As Paul said "need to do this programmatically" observer pattern can offer custom control. I am not sure but selectedTag binding could be more simple solution.